# Adding listeners in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, listener

My question is very simple: I'm trying to add a WindowListener and an onClose Listener (or Listener in general), but what I don't know how to do is where to add the code in Netbeans 8.0.

I have this doubt because Netbeans creates the JFrame entirely by itself, and hides that code. I have to add the Listener somewhere in this custom code created by Netbeans or in the Class Constructor, or any other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add many listeners to the JFrame using **`JFrame's Properties -> Events`** and **`Properties`** (**`Bindings`** can help you sometimes too).

If you don't get what you need, just place your code into the **constructor** or - if it's a lot -  make **private method** you *call* in the ctor.

I mostly prefer a private method than putting all into ctor, but that's really something of your choice.

**Example:**

```
public class Example extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    public Example()
    {
        initComponents(); // This is generated by NB - do NOT remove!

        addListeners(); // add listeners here
    }


    /**
     * Adds listeners to the frame
     */ 
    private void addListeners()
    {
        // Add your listeners here as usual
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
            {
                /* ... */
            }

            /* Other methods of WindowListener ... */
        });
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Just one thing here: Add your listeners **after** `initComponents()` - that's the *generated* method witch initializes all components - otherwise some components may not be ready.

Comment: Thanks. I have the JFrame1 that opens the JFrame2 with a button. How keep the JFrame1 Enabled(false) as longs as the JFrame2 is Visible?

Comment: This seems to be another question. There are many ways, one are Listeners, but you can also use a reference to `JFrame1`. Btw. possible a dialog is a better solution here? Those can be set as *modal*, what seems to me the solution for this.

Comment: What you mean by a dialog? Something like a message saying that the JFrame2 is already visible?

Comment: No, i mean implementing JFrame2 as a `JDialog` (instead of `JFrame`).